# In the program below how do I display the name of the region with the lowest number of accidents in the findLowest function?

Tags: c++

```
int getNumAccidents(string );
void findLowest(double , double , double , double , double);

int main()
{
    string regName;
    double north = 0;
    double south = 0;
    double east = 0;
    double west = 0;
    double central = 0;
    double lowest;


    regName = "North";
    north = getNumAccidents(regName);
    regName = "South";
    south = getNumAccidents(regName);
    regName = "East";
    east = getNumAccidents(regName);
    regName = "West";
    west = getNumAccidents(regName);
    regName = "Central";
    central = getNumAccidents(regName);


    findLowest(north, south, east, west, central);

    return 0;
}
```

The getNumAccidents function allows the user to enter the number of accidents reported in each region.

```
int getNumAccidents(string regionName) 
{   
    double number;

    cout << "\nEnter number of accidents for " << regionName << " area: " << endl;
    cin >> number;

    while (number <= -1)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter a positive number: " << endl;
        cin >> number;

    }

    //cout << "Region: " << regionName << " Number: " << number << endl;

    return number;
}
```

The findLowest function determines which region had the lowest number of accidents and that region's name. But how do I make it display the region's name with the lowest number of accidents?

```
void findLowest(double n, double s, double e, double w, double c) 
{
    double lowest = n;

    if (s < lowest)
    {
        lowest = s;

    }
    if (e < lowest)
    {   
            lowest = e;

    }
    if (w < lowest)
    {
        lowest = w;

    }
    if (c < lowest)
    {
        lowest = c;

    }

    cout << "\nThe least number of accidents was " << lowest << "." << endl;

    //cout << "The area was " << r << "." << endl;
}
```

Comment: When I do that the function shows the last region name "Central". It doesn't show the name of the region with the lowest number of accidents.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a struct with the fields as `double` and `string`.

```
struct A
{ 
   double count;
   string region;
};
```

Store each region name and its corresponding count in it. The `findLowest` will look like this:

```
void findLowest(A n, A s, A e, A w, A c) 
{

     double low=n.count;
     string reg=n.region;
     if(s.count<low)
     {
         low=s.count;
         reg=s.region;
      }

     if(e.count<low)
     {
         low=e.count;
         reg=e.region;
      }
      if(w.count<low)
     {
         low=w.count;
         reg=w.region;
      }
     if(c.count<low)
     {
         low=c.count;
         reg=c.region;
      }
cout << "\nThe least number of accidents was " << low << "." << endl;

cout << "The area was " << reg << "." << endl;
}
```

Another way of doing this is, using `C++ pair<string, double>`. The internal implementation of `pair` is again a `struct`. You can access the first element using `first` and second element using `second`.

```
pair< string, double > P;
P=make_pair("north", 12.12);
cout<<P.first<<" "<<P.second<<endl; //prints north 12.12..
```

Yet another way of doing this is using `C++ STL set`. Create a `set< pair <double, string  > >`. For this you need not find the lowest value explicitly. The `set` automatically sorts the elements inserted into it. The sample code looks like this:

```
set< double, string > St;
St.insert(make_pair(12.34, "north"));
St.insert(make_pair(34.56, "south"));
St.insert(make_pair(10.12, "east"));
cout<<St.begin()->second<<endl; //prints 'east'..
```

I am not sure whether you are familiar with `set` or not. But [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/) is a reference to it.

Comment: Is there a way I could do this without using a struct?